# return raw url source code using python

Tags: python, html

I've using python to retrieve the source code from a URL, however the URL in question has scripts that evaluate upon the loading of the page. As a result the body of the html returned is empty when using python, but when i visit the webpage manually it shows all kinds of posts in the body of the html code. Is there a way to force it to populate and evaluate the html?

In short when I use the file > Save button in Chrome on an HTML page, the resulting html code does not match the HTML saved using python. How can i resolve this?

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a web browser tool that can interpret javascript just like this one :[splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)